# How to embedded Excel file in ASP.Net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, vba

How to view excel file in ASP.Net page using c#?

I need to view excel file in asp.net form and access the all excel functionality in this excel sheet.
**Note:**
Excel sheet will open inside the form tag, it means open within a page, not open separate file.

***Like:*** Update fields, Merge fields, Wrap cells, Format the fields and apply text color. whatever Excel sheet have functionality all will be work asp.net excel page.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create your own GoogleDocs.

Comment: I am trying the following code.but it gives dialog box for opening/saving file.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

string sFile = Server.MapPath("MyExcel.xls");

FileStream fs = new FileStream(sFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

byte[] b = new byte[(int)fs.Length];

fs.Read(b, 0, (int)fs.Length);

fs.Close();

Response.Clear();

Response.BinaryWrite(b);

Response.End();

Answer (score 0):

You can upload this file to Google Doc and open it then chose File -> Publish to the Web -> Get html code and paste them.
Good luck.